# LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_state@590051772' has not been initialized.)

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

I don't understand why I'm catching an error in _mapController:

```
final MapController _mapController = MapController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _mapController.move(widget.latLng, _mapController.zoom);
  }
```

Comment: You are getting this issue because, the map controller is getting initiated and you are calling the move method. Try below code

final MapController _mapController = MapController();

  @override
  void initState() {
  //give some delay and execute
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {

  _mapController?.move(widget.latLng, _mapController.zoom);

  });
   
  super.initState();
  }

Comment: @AshishVE I also have this problem if I update the coordinates using setState inside the onPressed method at the button and without initialization in the initState method

Comment: Yes, try to call after some delay, it may work   final MapController _mapController = MapController();

  @override
  void initState() {
  //give some delay and execute
  Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {

  _mapController?.move(widget.latLng, _mapController.zoom);

  });
   
  super.initState();
  }

Comment: @AshishVE tried it doesn't work. maybe the thing is that higher up the tree I have a StreamBuilder that updates the coordinates and gives it to this widget?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but try like this ? :

```
  late MapController _mapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _mapController = MapController();
    _mapController.move(widget.latLng, _mapController.zoom);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: tried and got the same error(

Comment: Ok ok, so do it like the other with "?" Null Safety

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
MapController? _mapController;
//or try this-> MapController _mapController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _mapController.move(widget.latLng, _mapController.zoom);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises because you start using the mapcontroller before the build function starts which has the necessary configuration for the map. Try to put this line

```
 _mapController.move(widget.latLng, _mapController.zoom);
```

inside a method for example (_moveMap) and call it inside the build function when pressing a button.

like this:

```
 child: ElevatedButton(
        child:Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined,
        color: Colors.blue,) ,
        onPressed:_moveMap ,
      )),
```